# cat: illegal option -- 2 while merging

Tags: command-line, macos

```
wlan-141056:part_u_2 prova$ ls
-2e-5_cas 0_cas     10e-5_cas 20e-5_cas 40e-5_cas 5e-5_cas
wlan-141056:part_u_2 prova$ cat -2e-5_cas 0_cas > prova
cat: illegal option -- 2 usage: cat [-benstuv] [file ...]
```

What's wrong with merging two files using cat ?

Answer (score 4):

The first file you want to `cat` starts with a `-` so `cat` considers it to be an option. But as there is no option `2` (see the usage string) it throws an error.

Use one of

```
cat ./-2e-5_cas 0_cas > prova
cat -- -2e-5_cas 0_cas > prova
```

instead (the second is better for scripts etc).

PS: In general it is recommend to *not* use `-` as the first character of a filename to prevent exactly these issues.